# Chart.js | Bar Chart - Reduce the size of the axis

Tags: chartjs, chart.js

I am new to Chart.js (3.7) and I would like to reduce the size of the axis, I would like to show only one bar with the smallest size since I have to embedded it in another application

[image]

Comment: This question will be answered well in https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

`barThickness` is probably what you're looking for.

> #### barThickness
>
> If this value is a number, it is applied to the width of
> each bar, in pixels. When this is enforced, barPercentage and
> categoryPercentage are ignored.
>
> If set to 'flex', the base sample widths are calculated automatically
> based on the previous and following samples so that they take the full
> available widths without overlap. Then, bars are sized using
> barPercentage and categoryPercentage. There is no gap when the
> percentage options are 1. This mode generates bars with different
> widths when data are not evenly spaced.
>
> If not set (default), the base sample widths are calculated using the
> smallest interval that prevents bar overlapping, and bars are sized
> using barPercentage and categoryPercentage. This mode always generates
> bars equally sized.

[ChartJS | Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness)